# Why ‘orientationchange’ event is not firing on browser resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation

I am using below javascript code. But it’s not working on browser resize. And I also used foundation (zurb) framework in this project.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).on("orientationchange", function () {
        alert("The orientation has changed!");
        // I want to do my other stuff here which is depend on Landscap or portrait
    });
</script>
```

Please let me know what I missed here.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`orientation change` is portrait / landscape change

`resize` is a different event

you can as well look for `load` which is a required event in most similar cases `load` will be fired when the page loads first so you can do some initial adjustments.

```
$(window).on("orientationchange load resize", function () {
    alert("The orientation has changed!");
    // I want to do my other stuff here which is depend on Landscap or portrait
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
// Find matches
var mql = window.matchMedia("(orientation: portrait)");

// If there are matches, we're in portrait
if(mql.matches) {  
    // Portrait orientation
} else {  
    // Landscape orientation
}

// Add a media query change listener
mql.addListener(function(m) {
    if(m.matches) {
        // Changed to portrait
    }
    else {
        // Changed to landscape
    }
});
```